# Short story with an old programmer about to lose his job who triggers a Trojan Horse that only he can fix

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, isaac-asimov, computers

I remember reading a short story many years ago (1980s) about an old computer programmer who was about to be forced into mandatory retirement.  After receiving the news from his boss he returns to his office, makes a phone call and places an order for some obscure part number or form number, or something.  This order then triggers a huge catastrophe in the system and, because only he understands this part of the system, is not let go from his job.

I think this may have been an Isaac Asimov story, but I can't be sure of this.

Comment: Don't know the original story, but we've got a real-life example: http://www.wftv.com/news/26986709/detail.html?cxntlid=cmg_cntnt_rss (whack-a-mole programmer put a timeout in the game so he'd have job security).

Comment: Is there a list of short stories by I. Asimov that includes a short synopsis of each?

Comment: Yes, if you have a large public or University library (we're talking LA/New York sized public library here) they probably subscribe to Wilson's Short Story Index http://www.hwwilson.com/bus/storeindec.cfm 

If anyone can get access to this resource you could answer a lot of questions here.  Sadly, my library has no rational reason to purchase it.

Comment: @oosterwal Wikipedia has a large list of Asimov's work, but the man wrote so much that there's still quite a few titles without articles.

Comment: Doesn't that sound vaguely Tron-ish?

Comment: @oosterwal http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isaac_Asimov_short_stories_bibliography

Comment: @oosterwal : There's *Jenkins’ Spoiler-Laden Guide to Isaac Asimov* at http://www.asimovreviews.net/

Comment: Sounds like a DailyWTF article

Comment: What the question describes is not a Trojan (Horse), but merely a backdoor or magic knock.

Comment: Hello, @oosterwal! I don't know if you're still around. I posted a question at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/244683/short-story-about-a-programmer-whose-job-security-consists-of-knowing-obscure-fa I was just referred to your question - I think we read the same story. If you're still looking can, you check out my question which contains other details. Maybe between us we can jog something loose

Answer (score 21):

My name is Dennis Delaney. I wrote a novelet for Creative Computing magazine in 1979 entitled "The Contradiction Theory" that was published in their book *[Tales of the Marvelous Machine](https://archive.org/details/Tales_of_The_Marvelous_Machine)*. It was a murder mystery/sf tale dealing with the then unknown concept of a Trojan Horse virus. Is this it?

Detective Tobias Warton tries to solve the murder of Philip Carmichael, a man who's been trying to unite Mechanists and Anti-Mechanists, during his secret visit World Computer and Robot. His method of death is simple to determine. The air in his room was removed via a computer command. Detective Warton has to determine whether this was a matter of mere error, or if it is something more malicious.

Partway through the story, a programmer, Raudive Allen, claims to have entered the fatal program into the system as a Trojan Horse, triggered by a dial code to Nahum Sprague, but also claims that the program was slid under his door, and he didn't know who gave it to him or that it was going to be used to target Carmichael.

> Ultimately, it is revealed that it was the Governor who engineered the fatal incident in order to foment chaos.

Comment: Hi Dennis, welcome to the science fiction and fantasy stack exchange.  It is very possible that it is your story I'm thinking about.  I'll have to look back through my Creative Computing magazines.  Thank you for this bit of information!

Comment: So we have you to thank for inventing Trojan Horses?

Comment: Seems like there is enough information in the OP's question for you to identify it if it's yours.  Did your story involve the triggering of the trojan via a phoned order for an obscure part number?

Comment: I found a link to an Internet Archive copy of the magazine as included above. I don't think this one is a match for the question after all.

Answer (score -3):

This could be The Bastard Operator from Hell

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bastard_Operator_From_Hell

I've tried searching for the specific story but couldn't find anything, I couldn't find an indexed version of the archive.