# Looking for old (late 70s, early 80s) book with computer & SF short stories including 20 Questions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

The story I specifically remember was called (I think) 20?S or 20QS. It was about someone who had written a computer program that could play 20 questions. I think it was written by the child of a professional computer programmer, and the father was blown away that it actually worked.

> The twist was that the kid looked at the last letter of the question and if it was an "e" or some other letter, answered Yes; otherwise no. The theory was that no one would waste a question they already knew the answer to, so in this way they'd never get caught.

I believe it was in a collection of short stories, all about tech, SF and computers. I seem to recall it was connected with Creative Computing magazine, but all of the Amazon & Google searching I've done around this was to no avail.

Does anyone have any ideas or leads on where to look?

Comment: Please give away the twist at the end. The title as you recall it was literally "20?s" and not something like "20 questions" or "twenty questions"?

Comment: You should really give away the twist, under a spoiler tag if you think it's necessary. Twists are usually memorable and might make someone remember the book.

Comment: Thanks.   SPOILER -- the twist was that the kid basically looked at the last letter of the question and if it was an "e" or some other letter, answered Yes; otherwise no. The theory was that no one would waste a question they already knew the answer to, so in this way they'd never get caught.  And yes, I believe the title was actually "20?S" but maybe "20QS" or something.  Thanks

Comment: Nothing like that in either volume of "The Best of Creative Computing".  It was fun looking in them again though.

Comment: Right. The volume I'm thinking of wasn't in the actual magazine, but I seem to think it was maybe by the same publisher, or the same editor, or something else. It was a paperback bound book, collecting maybe 20-30 stories.

Answer (score 6):

And the answer is:
"XX?S" by Brian McCue, in the volume: *[Tales of the marvelous machine: 35 stories of computing](https://archive.org/details/Tales_of_The_Marvelous_Machine)* ([Amazon Link](http://a.co/gZhVqBL))

> "How does it work?"
>   "Oh, well, I'm not really sure, I mean, it was almost three days ago that I wrote it."
>   "None of that! How does it work?"
>   "Very simple..."
>   "I might have know."

> "... it takes your question, ignores the question mark, and looks at the last letter. If that letter is an 'e' it responds 'YES': otherwise, it answers 'NO'."

> "But that's not playing Twenty Questions!"

> "It might as well be. Since a smart player like you, Mr. Hertz, would never ask it a question if he knew the answer, he would never give it a chance to be inconsistent. And when he gets a YES to a direct guess about what the answer is, he won't wait around and ask more questions, he'll get out of the program. So the computer never selects an object at all; it just lets the guy create one."

> I had to think about that for a while, but it finally made sense.

Comment: You can (and should) add more details and then accept your answer once the 48 hours is up.

Comment: FWIW, "Tales of the Marvelous Machine" was brought up in a (probably incorrect) answer at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/what-short-story-has-an-old-programmer-about-to-lose-his-job-who-triggers-a-troj/5957#5957, which was how I knew where to find the Internet Archice copy to get the quote.

Comment: Nice job! Incidentally, when I was researching this, I saw in the April 1980 issue of Creative Computing an article by David Gerrold on making BASIC game program input more user-friendly!