# Short story about a programmer whose job security consists of knowing obscure failure modes of the system

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, computers

It's science-y and fiction-y, but I don't know if it's science fiction-y. It is - or was - speculative fiction. In my mind it's comparable to Vernor Vinge's "True Names" but without the virtual reality. What I mean to say is that, if one considers True Names SF, then I think it's fair to consider this short story SF as well.  I think I read this short story maybe in my mid 20s to 30s. So maybe it came out some time between, say, 1985 to 1995. OTOH, my memory is crappy, so maybe the timeframe is between 1980 and 2000. It was in a computer trade journal, but I can't recall which one - but it was something generic like "Data" or "Computer." I *think* the title of the story was something like "Privacy and the Gray-haired Programmer." I do not recall the author's name.

The story is about an older programmer (a character with whom I can finally identify) working in, I think, a bank. He's well-versed in vestigial COBOL programs on which the firm depends for some minuscule, but critical portion of their business. COBOL is a computer language used mainly in some business applications. My younger self detested COBOL - most of us with a scientific or engineering bent did.  It was easy for us to imagine that COBOL would become arcane (and I suppose that very old code is usually arcane, regardless the language).

His life is comfortable until he gets a new, young boss who gives him notice that his skills are antiquated and his services no longer required. He doesn't panic. He doesn't get angry. He doesn't break things - quite. He simply goes to his computer and initiates a legitimate transaction that causes the system to break. Everyone is panicking. Nobody knows how to fix it. Eventually they call in the one guy who knows COBOL to fix it.  (I think it was COBOL. It might have been PL/I now that I'm second guessing myself. But I think it was COBOL.)  He fixes the bug - we discover he has a list of known, obscure bugs that only manifest in rare circumstances. His retirement is canceled and in fact his new boss is canned. That was the story.

I've checked pro-quest. Can't get close.

It's been a very long time since I read it. The details are not exact. But that's the gestalt of it.

Addendum:
I'm convinced the story I'm looking for is the same that @mixxiphoid links to below. However, if we are thinking of the same story, then the person who answered is not correct.  Also, it's possible it's an Asimov story, though my vague recollection was that the author had a mundane name.

Comment: Sounds like many of the real-life projects that I've been involved with!

Comment: I don't know, sounds like something which may have (and probably already has) happened in our plain real world. I don't think it's on-topic for this stack but you say want to try on [literature.se].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Short story with an old programmer about to lose his job who triggers a Trojan Horse that only he can fix](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/2635/short-story-with-an-old-programmer-about-to-lose-his-job-who-triggers-a-trojan-h)

Comment: I had a recurring chunk of work with my employer converting FORTRAN code to C, C++, and perl (as well as other upgrade projects.)  It seems unlikely to me that such a thing could happen at a bank, but not impossible. I'm quite sure there are indeed multi-million dollar companies, and probably various governments with critical functions tied up in antiquated software. You see the occasional ad for programmers with ... 'what kind of skills???'

Comment: @Mixxiphoid I think that's the same story I was thinking about!  The author who responded relates an interesting story that he wrote, but that's not the story I was thinking about.  I'm going to direct that questioner here, if he's still around and maybe between the two of us we can think of more details. This is the first big lead I've had since I started looking - somebody else who SEEMS to have read the same story!

Comment: I feel like I've read a few episodes of this show on https://blog.codinghorror.com/

Comment: This feels plausible enough to be a true story, so calling it sci-fi seems questionable.

Comment: I accept the critiques of the question; however, it's not so clear cut to me.
See, for example, Le Guin's response to Atwood at:
https://bookriot.com/what-is-speculative-fiction/

"Atwood also mentions a debate she had with Ursula K. Le Guin. Le Guin said that science fiction is speculative fiction when what is written about could really happen, whereas narratives that cannot, under any circumstances, happen in our world (i.e. Earthsea) classify separately as fantasy."

We agree that the details of the story could and since it was written probably have happened in our world.